# mysql> SHOWing GRANTS for all users

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Currently I perform a manual two-step procedure to get the grants information for all the users.

**Step 1:**

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
```

**Step 2:**

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR '«user»'@'«host»'; -- Repeated for all user-host pairs.
```

Is there a single command to give me this information?

Comment: *Is there a single command to give me this information?*  Yes. This command is `CALL stored_procedure_name;` where SP performs all the commands described in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve privileges for all users from information_schema:

`select grantee, group_concat(privilege_type) from information_schema.user_privileges group by grantee`

Comment: Only a part of privileges will be returned. Compare your query output (with WHERE for to return the privileges for definite user with root privileges) and SHOW GRANTS output for the same user.